# spring @Scheduled annotaion works on Local Websphere but does not work on Websphere installed on Severs

Tags: spring

Spring @Scheduled(cron = "${cron expression}") works on the websphere in local machine but not on the non prod servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Thread pool in the different Webshere to check whats the difference I asume your problem might be there.

Else, a more complicated solution is to pass in a custom threadpool for your schedule tasks.

To do this create a new configuration class for the Scheduler and add a custom Threadpool

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

You can find more references here https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/

Comment: tried it but didn't work. May be need to check the Thread pool in Websphere

Comment: yes that what i meant with "You should check the Thread pool in the different Webshere to check whats the difference I asume your problem might be there."